# GSM 900D Module Limit for Text Messages Sending & Receiving

Tags: python, sms, gsm, sms-gateway

I have a GSM Modem SIM 900D. I am using it with my server and Python code to send and receive messages. I want to know how many Text SMS I could send and receive through this GSM modem per minute.

Comment: Could you please expand on your question? Are you concerned about a hardware or software bottleneck? Can you post your code?

Comment: I would expect the limit to be the minimum of the limits of the software, GSM modem and limits set by the mobile network you use

Comment: I want limit of GSM modem. that how many SMS per minute it could send. i am using Baud rate of 9600.
I got Python code for sending and receiving message from github https://github.com/rapidsms/pygsm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you consider all protocols involved, including radio part, 300+ messages across a good dozen of protocols would have to be sent in order to deliver outgoing SMS to SMSC, and a great deal of waiting and synchronization will have to be involved. This (high overhead) will be your limiting factor and you would probably get 10-15 SMS per minute or so.

Reducing overhead is only possible with a different connectivity methods, mostly to eliminate radio part and mobility management protocols. Usual methods are: connecting to a dedicated SMS gateway provider via whatever protocol they fancy, or acting as SMSC yourself and connecting to SS7 network directly.